# Scanning for beacons on iOS thru' web browser

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, eddystone, web-bluetooth

Is there any way to make a web page scan for beacons on iOS ? I know that no iOS web browser supports Web Bluetooth at the present. I even could not find any information about if Chrome team is planning to add support for Web Bluetooth for Chrome on iOS.

Is there any other way to scan for the beacons on iOS thru' web browsers (be it Safari or Chrome) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unfortunately, Google can't add Web Bluetooth to Chrome for iOS without Apple's participation**, and Apple has given no indication that they are supporting the Web Bluetooth project.

Understand that Apple restricts web browsers on iOS to use Safari or Safari web views, which has the same JavaScript engine and bindings as Safari.  Google Chrome for iOS is required to use the same internal rendering and JavaScript engine as Safari, which simply does not support Web Bluetooth.

Bottom line:  While it is possible that Apple will one day decide to join the Web Bluetooth party, there can be no support on third party iOS browsers until Apple decides to do so.

Comment: Thanks David for a reply. Is there any way a pwa running on an iOS device can scan for the beacons ? Library like Android Beacon Library is meant to be used in an native app only or such a library can scan for the beacons thru' pwa as well ? Many thanks...

Comment: It would have to be wrapped in a native container like Cordova to make this possible using native bindings.

Comment: WebBLE simple web browser that supports an initial subset of the web bluetooth javascript APIs. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/webble/id1193531073?ls=1&mt=8