# To what extent is web bluetooth usable in mobile devices?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, web-bluetooth

From my understanding, the web bluetooth api found here:

https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/

is good with chrome across devices, but other browsers do not support it. Is this true? 
this stackoverflow post says otherwise but it was two years ago and i'm just not sure if its even possible with IOS or a significant number of devices.

[Scanning for beacons on iOS thru' web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45234339/scanning-for-beacons-on-ios-thru-web-browser)

I also saw this hackaday site that says you need the WebBLE app to do this, is that true?

https://hackaday.io/project/164733-pisugar-battery-for-raspberry-pi-zero/log/167217-use-web-bluetooth-to-connect-your-pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Web Bluetooth Implementation Status](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md) is the best source for status.

On mobile: Android support via Chrome, Samsung Internet. iOS support via [WebBLE](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/webble/id1193531073).